# Upgrading RAM on ASUS N53SN Laptop

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, asus-laptop

I'm just not quite sure what this means. The laptop already came with 8GB of RAM. And I'm guessing it's an onboard module. Does this mean I can put 8GB more to make it 16GB?[my laptop configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PsnO.jpg) My laptop ram is dual core, does it mean that I can not upgrade the RAM? [Link to manual: file 0409.PDF is in English](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/Apps/eManual/eManual_N53J.zip).

Comment: I would say no, you can upgrade, but if you upgrade,  upgrade all the RAM to quad-core.

Answer (score 0):

Your manual does not specify what RAM nor how many slots there are for memory modules.

'Dual core' and 'quad core' are terms used to refer to CPUs, not memory; memory is 'single rank' (faster) or 'dual rank'.

Your memory is in onboard modules; open the door underneath and find the exact part number of the memory there; if there are two memory slots vacant, buy two more modules of the exact memory to expand it, as reddit users report [mix-and-match does not work](https://www.reddit.com/r/24hoursupport/comments/16tndl/installing_new_ram_woes_asus_n53s_corsair_ddr3/).

If there are no free memory slots, then order the next larger size of memory from the same manufacturer with the same specs.